# Upload file to Dropbox with PHP

Tags: php, dropbox

I have the following code to upload a file to Dropbox

```
        $context = $this->createRequestContext($url, "PUT");
        curl_setopt($context, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
        $fh = fopen($src_file, 'rb');
        curl_setopt($context,CURLOPT_HEADER,true);
        curl_setopt($context, CURLOPT_INFILE, $fh); // file pointer
        curl_setopt($context, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, filesize($src_file));
        $context = $this->createRequestContext($url, "PUT", $content);
        $meta = json_decode(self::execCurlAndClose($context));
        fclose($fh);
        return $meta;
```

My problem is that everytime i get the following error as a response:

```
["error"]=> string(121) "Upload failed. Content-Type must not be empty and not one of ('application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'multipart/form-data')"
```

I am trying to upload any type of file for now , but in the future I would like to upload only pdf files. Could you help me with an indication with what am i doing wrong ?

This is the header:

```
["method"]=>
string(3) "PUT"
["header"]=>
string(64) "Content-Length: 230783
  Content-Type: application/octet-stream
"
```

Comment: The error message seems quite clear - you need to check what Content-Type header you're setting.

Comment: @andrewsi thank you for the answer , but the header does not contain the types from the error message!

Comment: Did you try the [Dropbox_API](http://code.google.com/p/dropbox-php/wiki/Dropbox_API) for php?

Comment: It doesn't include a Content-Type header, which you need to include

Answer (score 0):

You need to add:

```
curl_setopt($context, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type' => 'image/jpeg'));
```

and fill in the appropriate mimetype. If you need to determine that type, then use [fileinfo](http://php.net/fileinfo)